# Font is not rendering proparly in same resolution devices

Tags: android

I've two devices samsung s6 edge and Galaxy note 4. When running the application with custom fonts, It's not looking consistent even-though both have same resolution (640 dpi). [image: Samsung s6 edge]

[image: Galaxy Note 4]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, S6 edge is xxxhdpi device when Note 4 is xxhdpi. If you follow [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) you will see, that this means different resolutions for icons and fonts. Also as first device has resolution 1440x2560, second has 1080x1920, which also explains different sizes.

Comment: Resolution is the same for both models - it is 1440x2560. So the only problem is density.

Comment: @AlexanderMironov, sorry, my mistake

Comment: both have same density 4

Comment: I've checked with this code.        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);